# Downloading subfolders files in S3 bucket from boto2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, bucket

I am easily able to download the files from the bucket, but now I need to make a download from a particular folder in my S3 bucket.

I am currently using the below code :

```
import boto
import boto.s3.connection

access_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
secret_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX+XXXXXXXXXXXXX'

bucket_name = 'my_Bucket'
conn =   boto.connect_s3('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX','XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX+XXXXXXXXXXXXX')
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)
bucket_list = bucket.list()

LOCAL_PATH = '/Users/tcssig/Documents/EPG/'

for l in bucket_list:
    keyString = str(l.key)
    d = LOCAL_PATH + keyString
    try:
        l.get_contents_to_filename(d)
    except OSError:
        if not os.path.exists(d):
            os.mkdir(d)
```

How do I get files downloaded from my_folder in the bucket my_bucket ?

Comment: You are not using boto3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the particular folder path as prefix to the `list()` method

```
bucket_list = bucket.list(prefix='particular/folder/path')
```

Comment: Using the folder path as '/folderName_inside_bucket/' doesn't download any files present in the folder.

Comment: Print `bucket_list` to see whether it lists the files present inside the folder.

Comment: bucket_list is created as `<boto.s3.bucketlistresultset.BucketListResultSet object at 0x104bf4828>`, when I try to iterate over it and print the contents, I get empty output.

Comment: Can you please try removing the leading `/` in folder path. It should be `folderName_inside_bucket/`

Comment: thanks for your help, its working for me now, had to correct the part of script which creates destination folder on my local.